# Typescript. Type is not assignable to type union type [2322]

Tags: typescript, generics

Is it correct behavior for TS not to assign return function value in this case?

```js
type RetType = string| null | object;
const returnGenericString = <T extends RetType = string>(): T => 'test' as any;
// it's okay
const value1: string | number = 'test';
// it's not okay
const value2: string | number = returnGenericString();
```

I got such an error:

```
Type 'RetType' is not assignable to type 'string | number'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | number'.
```

If it's right behavior, so please explain me why.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShwBVzQLxQM7AE4EsB2A5gD5R4CuANhVCQPYBGAVhAMbADcAUC7XplFnhkseAOIQ8EXCwDK2fAShoAPAigQAHsAkATdLHhJISjPMIA+ABQBKAFxQ1Kc1ADk2zC6gBDfV7wguTgB6IKgcYBd9WgBrLxBuXn4ANy8KMggARntMXEIaUjIAW3opEzcIDy4QsIj9PFpgKBi4hL5GlLSIACZss0UScmLStEFgYTEJKRxZPpt2IA)

Comment: Looks like a big for me.

Comment: @IngoBürk But `T` is `string` by default: `T extends RetType = string`. And there is no problem with just a `string` type: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShwBVzQLxQM7AE4EsB2A5gD5R4CuANhVCQPYBGAVhAMbADcAUC7XplFnhkseAOIQ8EXCwDK2fAShoAPAigQAHsAkATdLHhJISjPMIA+ABQBKAFxQ1Kc1ADk2zC6gBDfV7wguTgB6IKgcYBd9WgBrLxBuXn4ANy8KMggAJntMXEITQWBhMQkpHFkzAht2IA)

Comment: this is some weird contextual typing going on here... the compiler *wants* to infer `string | number` for `T` (note that if you [break the contextual typing](https://tsplay.dev/wg6AvW) then this does not happen).  Since it cannot do that, (`string | number` does not extend `RetType`), the compiler ends up failing to infer `T` from context.  *Normally* when inference fails it would fall back to the default (which is `string`), but that is not happening here.  I don't know why.  So this is surprising to me, although I couldn't say if it's a bug or not.

Comment: Feels buggy given the [generic default doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) says "If a default type is specified and inference cannot choose a candidate, the default type is inferred." but that's not happening here maybe?  I mean, inference "chose" a candidate of `string | number` but had to reject it.  Then instead of looking at the default it just fell back to the constraint.  I can't find an existing bug report about this but it would be interesting for someone to file one (or find one)

Comment: Well I have looked more and I cannot find an existing [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues).  *Maaaaybe* I'll file one myself although I just did this for another question so I might want to wait a while to do it.